# react native issue on runnig app on android emulator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-virtual-device

[image]When i run react-native run-android it says build successful in terminal bu t it displays an error in android emulator that cannot find entry file in any of the roots. But there exist index.js in my project. 
   I have tried many solution but still this problem cannot be solved.

Comment: Please show the exact error.

Comment: please copy the terminal log here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52859507/9051904   I have added the image of my issue.